# How to calculate the program run time

Tags: c#, timer

I set a timer

```
DispatcherTimer messageTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
messageTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(messageTimer_Tick);
messageTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
```

And a

```
<Label Name="time"  Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1"   />
```

How to caculate the run time and show it in the label?

Comment: Do you mean you want to display how long the program has been running for? And just to confirm, this is WPF right?

Comment: I'd use a StopWatch for this rather than a normal timer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: @JonEgerton: I don't think Stopwatch is appropriate here, the OP needs to update a label every second and it doesn't appear that the Stopwatch class has any events to notify when each second has elapsed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a timer is exactly what you need. Here is an idea of how you want to use it...

When your application starts you need to store the current system time, you can do this with a static property:

```
public static DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
```

(Alternatively, you can set this value from somewhere else, such as the `Main()` function)

Then create your timer as normal, with the `Tick` event. Don't forget to start your timer!

Then inside your `Tick` event handler, you can calculate the elapsed time and update the label:

```
public void messageTimer_Tick()
{
   TimeSpan elapsedTime = DateTime.Now - StartTime;
   myLabel.Content = elapsedTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
}
```